# How to use the comparator method in Rhino Java environment

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I am trying to override the `compareTo()` method for my class so as to sort the instances based on their dates.

When I run this program, I get incorrect results. 
I am writing in Javascript because I am working in a Rhino environment. I am not sure if it helps, but I am using the [execute-rhino-online](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-rhino-online) online editor to write the code:

```
var arrayList = java.util.ArrayList();
var Object1 = new java.util.HashMap();
var Object2 = new java.util.HashMap();
var Object3 = new java.util.HashMap();
Object1.put("Job Number", "222");
Object1.put("Date", java.util.Date(2017, 10, 11));
Object2.put("Job Number", "333");
Object2.put("Date", java.util.Date(2017, 10, 13));
Object3.put("Job Number", "111");
Object3.put("Date", java.util.Date(2017, 10, 10));
arrayList.add(Object1);
arrayList.add(Object2);
arrayList.add(Object3);

var comp = java.util.Comparator({
  compareTo: function(o1, o2) {
    var d1 = o1.get("Date");
    print(d1);
    var d2 = o2.get("Date");
    if (d1.before(d2)) {
      return -1;
    } else if (d1.after(d2)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
});
java.util.Collections.sort(arrayList, comp);
print(arrayList);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're overriding a non existent method

Change `compareTo:` to `compare:`

Check the javadocs for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html